# pandas: count rows within time moving window

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, count

```
import pandas as pd
d = [{'col1' : ' B', 'col2' : '2015-3-06 01:37:57'},
       {'col1' : ' A', 'col2' : '2015-3-06 01:39:57'},
       {'col1' : ' A', 'col2' : '2015-3-06 01:45:28'},
       {'col1' : ' B', 'col2' : '2015-3-06 02:31:44'},
       {'col1' : ' B', 'col2' : '2015-3-06 03:55:45'},
       {'col1' : ' B', 'col2' : '2015-3-06 04:01:40'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df['col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['col2'])
```

For each row I want to count number of rows with same
values of 'col1' and time within window of past 10 minutes before time of this row(include). I'm interested in **implementation** which work **fast**

this source work very **slow** on big dataset:

```
dt = pd.Timedelta(10, unit='m')
def count1(row):
    id1 = row['col1']
    start_time = row['col2'] - dt
    end_time = row['col2']
    mask = (df['col1'] == id1) & ((df['col2'] >= start_time) & (df['col2'] <= end_time))
    return df.loc[mask].shape[0]

df['count1'] = df.apply(count1, axis=1)

df.head(6)

    col1    col2    count1
0   B   2015-03-06 01:37:57     1
1   A   2015-03-06 01:39:57     1
2   A   2015-03-06 01:45:28     2
3   B   2015-03-06 02:31:44     1
4   B   2015-03-06 03:55:45     1
5   B   2015-03-06 04:01:40     2
```

Notice: column 'col2' is date sensitive, not only time

Answer (score 3):

The problem is, that `apply` is very expensive.
One option is to optimize the code via cython or with the use of numba.

[This](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html) might be helpful.

Another option is the following:

1. Create a column with timestamps from col2
2. Create a column with ids which group the timestamps by your 10 min criterium
3. Create a combined column with the previous created ids and col1 as in `df['time_ids'].map(str) + df['col1']`
4. Use `groupby` to determine the number of equal rows. Something like: `df.groupby(df['combined_ids']).size()`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
df.col2=pd.to_datetime(df.col2)
df.groupby([pd.Grouper(key='col2',freq='H'),df.col1]).size().reset_index(name='count')
```